# How do I analyze this gate drive for power electronics?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, mosfet-driver, gate-driving

I'm a noob at electronics. I found this gate drive configuration online and wanted to analytically solve the gate-source voltage of the switching FET.

The gate drive IC has the following characteristics:
Vlow = 30mV, Vhigh = 12V, trise=17.5ns, tfall=16.5ns, Ton=1.7us, Tperiod=4.6us

From what I read, **when the clock signal is HIGH**, R1 and D1 are conducting... Using Kirchoff's voltage law...

V1 - VR1 - VD(f) - Vgate = 0

&

VR1 = Iin*R1

What is Iin, is it the output drive current (1.5A) for the gate drive IC I am looking at? https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1693fa.pdf

**When the clock signal is LOW**, R2 and Q1 are conducting...

V1 - VR2 + Vbe - Vgate = 0

Vgate = V1 - Iin*R2 + Vbe

.......

None of these analytical results match with LTSpice simulation... Am I calculating things incorrectly? Is I_in, the same for R2 as it is for R1? (this doesn't make sense for it to be, what would Iin into R2 be?)

Appreciate your help ladies and gents...

[image]

Comment: First off all the gate current flows mostly during transitions (on to off and vice versa) only. To solve the gate current you have to know a gate capacitance of mosfet (see datasheet).

Comment: 10720 pF is the typical input capacitance into the FET, I assume this is the gate capacitance? https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfp4668pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153562c8528201d

Comment: The initial gate discharging peak current is Q1_Beta*(V1-0.7)/R2 and continously decreases as gate charge is falling.

Comment: The gate charging time constant is R1*10.7n , and initial charging peak current is (V1-0.7)/R1 and slowly decreases.

Comment: Not sure I am understanding... Wouldn't the gate charging time constant be with the internal resistor (Rgin*Ciss)? I=Q/t ... 161nC / (Rgin*Ciss) ? ... If it's with R1, the (V1-Vd)/Ig is redundant?

Comment: Also, V1 - Vr2 - Vbe = 0 --> Vr2 = (V1-Vbe) ... R2 = (V1-Vbe)/Ig .... Wouldn't V1 in this case be when the gate drive is pulled LOW? That would be (30mV-0.7V)... negative resistance...?

Comment: Rgin according datasheet is 1ohm and designers use R1 at least 10ohm(usually 22ohm) so it is negligible to count with Rgin.

Comment: In discharging the ig current flows through CE of Q1 transistor, not R2. R2 just controls this transistor.

Comment: One last question, how do you calculate for Beta of the Q1 transistor? The current gain Beta is a function of base and collector(=emitter) currents.... Base current must be much smaller than emitter current for me to have reasonable gain as shown in datasheets. But in LTSpice, my base current is nearly the same as my emitter current? How is the Beta found if you don't know your discharging peak current?

Comment: @MichalPodmanický example I worked on and ran into issue with current gain Beta... Ig(off-disch) = Q/tfall = 2.18A... & R2 = 3 Ohm (VOH-Vgsthr)/Ig(off) .... Beta=(Igoff*R2/(VOH-Vgsthr)) = (2.18A * 3Ohm)/(11.97V-5V) = 0.93 ... I have never seen a BJT with current gain rating of 0.93

Comment: Why you use such a low R2. Use 1kohm. The Q1 gives you gain you need (beta~200). The formula is Ic=Beta*Ib Of course, the R1 has to be low (like 22 ohm) because gate charging is not ampified with transistor.

Answer (score 1):

Do first a simulation (done with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110)).

Then cut according to the simulation into several pieces (proper equations).
Note that some "components" are "non-linear" ...

[image]

[image]

[image]